# Permissions error when modifying a server image

Tags: php, image, permissions, upload

I am running a LINUX PHP/MySQL server on Amazon Lightsail (Ubuntu) - I am able to upload JPG images just fine, permission is set to 644 on them (and 777 on the folder containing images, but not the parent folder) - when I try to edit the image and re-save it however from the admin area everything looks fine - until I reload the page, nothing saves. I get a saved confirmation, but it seems like there's some sort of permission error??

This is the error messages I am getting:

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 557960:tid 140345203373824] [client 174.68.163.183:58548] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP message: PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/includes/slim.php on line 142

PHP message: PHP Warning:

> file_put_contents(tmp/657a8d904271e_pet_posts_pkojd5dhuo46a7zle012.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/includes/slim.php on line 233'

**Code on slim.php file**

```
// LINE 142 CODE
if(!is_dir($path)){
    mkdir($path, 0755, true);
}

// LINE 233 CODE
private static function save($data, $path) {
if (!file_put_contents($path, $data)) {
    return false;
}
    return true;
}
```

The variables I'm using from other code in a different script:

```
// Get the requested remote url from the post
$url = $_GET['url'];

// Get the image data
// Will stop fetching at the 10 megabyte mark
$data = Slim::fetchURL($url, 10485760);

// get the file name from the url
$name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

// If you want to store the file in another directory pass the directory name as the third parameter.
// $file = Slim::saveFile($data, $name, 'my-directory/');
$file = Slim::saveFile($data, $name);
$filename = $file['path'];
```

Here's the Path code set to tmp - although I am not sure if its the right path?

```
// $path should have trailing slash
    public static function saveFile($data, $name, $path = 'tmp/', $uid = true) {
```

I am at a complete loss here, I am good with PHP code - not great with permissions, any ideas why the image wouldn't save as intended?

- I tried changing the tmp directory, did nothing
- I gave permissions on Ubuntu via SSH to allow other users besides root the ability to upload and it did fix 1 of the warnings but didn't change the result.

Comment: What do you mean by `tmp/` ? It is a local directory on your project? Or you mean the `/tmp`/ directory? what is your directory structure?

Comment: The general /tmp/ directory - for the images the structure is www.site.com/images/ads/

Comment: The warning showing that you are using `tmp/` not `/tmp/` and when it comes to file structure in OS this is a totally different thing.

Comment: It is using the exact same code though for the initial image upload - that's whats odd to me. I can upload the img just fine, but when I try and edit it while it is on the server, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that image is uploaded in the first time?

Comment: what does $path variable contain.

Comment: Yes, I have been using the script for 10 days, uploaded like 1,000 images already. I have been trying to add an "edit feature" to edit the image once on the server but nothing I do is working.